# Triple integral (determining boundaries):

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the given solid. Above the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and below the half cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I have great difficulty in determining the boundaries of the integrals. Could anyone provide me with a strategy to do this in this problem and for complex integrals such as these in general?

The correct answer is:

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} xyz\; dz \; dx \; dy$$

After which polar coordinates are used, however this procedure is clear to me.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing your second paragraph. Could you use a larger font?

Comment: @julien hahah sorry I guess I pressed a wrong button. Hahah but I'll make sure that its a bit bigger next time so you can read it too :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cartesians, you are finding the amount of space between the two surfaces, which is expressed as a function of $z$.  So you have to integrate

$$\int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dz\:$$

over the region in $(x,y)$ where $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} >x^2+y^2$.  This region happens to be the circle $x^2+y^2$=1.  Therefore, you get to integrate the above integral over the disk $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, and you should get as the volume

$$\int_{-1}^1 dy \: \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dx \: \int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dz\:$$

(I do not know where you got the $x y z$ from, as this is a volume calculation.)  You then use polar coordinates after doing the trivial integral over $z$ (or, equivalently, cylindrical coordinates), with $x = r \cos{\theta}$, $y=r \sin{\theta}$, and $dx\, dy = r \,dr \, d\theta$.  We then get for the volume

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \: \int_0^1 dr \: r (r-r^2) = 2 \pi \left ( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you. How did you figure out though that the region sqrt(x^2+y^2) > x^2 + y^2 corresponds to a circle?

Comment: Divide through by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$:  $x^2+y^2 \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1 \implies x^2+y^2 \le 1$.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. Thanks for your help :)